# Why is argv ended by a nullpointer?

Tags: c, exec

In the execve() man page it is said that argv is a list of string arguments which is ended by a null pointer. But what is the NP for? I mean, the number of arguments is stored in argc, so what's the point of the null pointer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`execve` does not take `argc` as a parameter, it manually counts the arguments you give as `argv` to determine `argc` itself.

This is for compatibility with `execl` which takes a variable number of arguments instead of an `argv` array.

Comment: Oh, sry, now I see it. Now that makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 5):

The count for `argc` is calculated by looking for this NULL.